# Maven unpack to disregard original folder

Tags: java, maven

One of my projects has a structure like this:

```
.\ca\<modulename>\dist\<modulename>.zip
```

I want to make a package that just has the zip files in a single package, so if I have submodules `mod1`, `mod2`, `modn`, I'll end up with:

```
ZIP CONTENT:
  mod1.zip
  mod2.zip
  ...
  modn.zip
```

What I've done so far is create a maven project and, using maven `dependency` and `assembly` plugins I got to this:

```xml
<plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unpack</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>unpack</goal>
                        </goals>

                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>es.xunta.emprego.cntxes</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>myproject-cas</artifactId>
                                    <version>${cas.version}</version>
                                    <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                                    <outputDirectory>target/dependency</outputDirectory>
                                    <type>zip</type>
                                    <includes>ca/**/dist/*.zip</includes>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptor>src/main/assembly/zip.xml</descriptor>
                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <!-- append to the packaging phase. -->
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

With this being `assembly/zip.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<assembly>
    <id>bin</id>
    <formats>
        <!-- formato de salida del empaquetado -->
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <directory>target/dependency</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>/**/dist/*.zip</include>
            </includes>
            <useDefaultExcludes>true</useDefaultExcludes>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

But this is respecting my original zip's folder structure, so the result is:

```
ZIP CONTENT
   ca\mod1\dist\mod1.zip
   ca\mod2\dist\mod2.zip
   ...
   ca\modn\dist\modn.zip
```

It might seem a small issue but the number of modules is big and gathering the different zip files is very annoying having to browse through every folder. I've been struggling with `assembly` and `dependency` but haven't found a way to achieve what I want. Note that I'm using wildcards (`ca/**/dist/*.zip`) because I don't know prior to compilation the name of the files that will be there.

Any help please?

Comment: As a workaround, have you considered using a separate `fileSet` for each module? You can have paths like `target/dependency/mod1/dist` inside `directory`, and only include `*.zip`.

Comment: I can't, my number of modules is dynamic and I need the pom to stay static :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if there's a way to do this but this question might help you find a way through : [execute ant / groovy script inside maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4257858/maven-copy-files-without-subdirectory-structure)

According to the linked answer, here is an ANT example (I can't try it right now) with the maven ANT plugin :

```xml
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>unpack</id>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>unpack</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <artifactItems>
                        <artifactItem>
                            <groupId>es.xunta.emprego.cntxes</groupId>
                            <artifactId>myproject-cas</artifactId>
                            <version>${cas.version}</version>
                            <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                            <outputDirectory>target/dependency</outputDirectory>
                            <type>zip</type>
                            <includes>ca/**/dist/*.zip</includes>
                        </artifactItem>
                    </artifactItems>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>move</id>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>run</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <target>
                        <copy todir="${project.basedir}/target/dependency" flatten="true">
                            <fileset dir="${project.basedir}/ca">
                                <include name="**/dist/*.zip"/>
                            </fileset>
                        </copy>
                    </target>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
    ...
</plugins>
```

At least, the version 3.0.3 of Maven is required in order to insure plugins execution order on same phase.

Comment: Thanks but this is not a real solution for me, I need to stick to Maven :(

Comment: MichelReap, it will be maven only - you don't need ant to use the maven-antrun-plugin.

Comment: See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4257858/maven-copy-files-without-subdirectory-structure

Answer (score 0):

Are `mod1.zip`, `mod2.zip`, etc. installed, or can they be installed into your local repository?  You could use the `maven-dependency-plugin`:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.whatever</groupId>
        <artifactId>mod1</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>zip</type>
    <dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.10</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/dist</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

This gets you back to maintaining this dependency list given a dynamic module list, but if you can figure out how to make the dependency list dynamic, then this might get you farther.

Answer (score 0):

You need a plugin between the dependency:unpack and the assembly:single task that flattens your resources.

You could fiddle with the resources:copy-resources task, but that probably won't do the trick, as confirmed here: [Maven : copy files without subdirectory structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4257858/maven-copy-files-without-subdirectory-structure)

For such cases, the maven ant plugin was created, as describe in @Fabien's answer, to invoke all sorts of non-standard behaviours.