# How can I get a maven assembly to omit all directories in the archive?

Tags: maven, archive, maven-assembly-plugin

Results I am after: I want a zip file without any directories in it. Files only.

My plugin entry:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <descriptor>src/assembly/descriptor.xml</descriptor>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                <finalName>${artifactId}-${pom.version}</finalName>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

My descriptor:

```
    <assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-2.0.0.xsd
http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0
http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0 ">
  <id>distribution</id>
  <formats>
    <format>zip</format>
  </formats>

  <!--<baseDirectory>target</baseDirectory>-->
  <!--<includeBaseDirectory>true</includeBaseDirectory>-->
  <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>


  <fileSets>
    <fileSet>
    <outputDirectory>./</outputDirectory>
      <includes>
        <include>src/**/*</include>
      </includes>
      <excludes>
        <exclude>**/assembly/**</exclude>
        <exclude>**/*.iml</exclude>
      </excludes>
    </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

...which results in a zip file:

```
user@host /cygdrive/c/Ws/someproject : zv subproject/target/somezip-SNAPSHOT.zip
Archive:  subproject/target/somezip-SNAPSHOT.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  01-11-2018 09:03   src/
        0  01-05-2018 09:01   src/main/
        0  01-09-2018 11:34   src/main/resources/
     1158  01-09-2018 11:34   src/main/resources/SomeFile_0_0_0.xml
     1836  01-09-2018 11:34   src/main/resources/AnotherFile_0_0_0.xml
    11636  01-09-2018 11:34   src/main/resources/SomeFile1_0_0_0.xml
     1171  01-09-2018 11:34   src/main/resources/SomeFile1_0_0_1.xml
     1398  01-09-2018 11:34   src/main/resources/SomeFile1_0_0_1.xml
     1006  01-09-2018 11:34   src/main/resources/SomeFile1_0_1_0.xml
     6691  01-09-2018 11:34   src/main/resources/SomeFile1_1_0_0.xml
     1641  01-09-2018 11:34   src/main/resources/SomeFile1_1_0_1.xml
     1937  01-09-2018 11:34   src/main/resources/SomeFile1_1_0_0.xml
     3181  01-09-2018 11:34   src/main/resources/SomeFile3_0_0_0.xml
     1774  01-09-2018 11:34   src/main/resources/SomeFile3_1_0_0.xml
     1185  01-09-2018 11:34   src/main/resources/SomeFile3_1_0_0.xml
    14609  01-09-2018 11:34   src/main/resources/SomeFile3_3_0_0.xml
    35711  01-09-2018 11:34   src/main/resources/SomeFile4_0_0_0.xml
    15805  01-09-2018 11:34   src/main/resources/SomeFile5_0_0_0.xml
     3491  01-09-2018 11:34   src/main/resources/SomeFile5_1_0_0.xml
    18757  01-09-2018 11:34   src/main/resources/SomeFile_0_0_0.xml
     1571  01-09-2018 11:34   src/main/resources/SomeFile_0_1_0.xml
     1063  01-09-2018 11:34   src/main/resources/SomeFile_0_1_1.xml
     1631  01-09-2018 11:34   src/main/resources/Wiggity.txt
---------                     -------
   140357                     13 files
```

Comment: Possibly related to [this q&a](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4257858/944849)?

Comment: That looks like it would work but I don't see how it gets into the maven repo afterwards.  Other projects depend on this zip. Maybe I could find a way to pass "flatten" to the zip process?